# pagination calculation algorithm

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I am trying to calculate pagination:

```
var pagination = {
 total: result.length,
 per_page: itemsPerPage,    // required
 current_page: currentPage, // required
 last_page: users.length / itemsPerPage,    // required
 from: (itemsPerPage * pageNumber) + 1,
 to: itemsPerPage * (pageNumber + 1)           //required
};
```

Let say the result length is 2, itemsPerPage is 5, currentPage is 1, I got this:

```
total: 2
per_page: 5
current_page: 1
last_page: 0.4
from: 6
to: 10
```

I think something is not right.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To round for the max value, you can use `Math.ceil` on `last_page`.

The items per page can be static, manually defined. Then, `from` can be `((currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage) + 1`.

- If current page is 1,  ( (1 -1) * 5) + 1 = 1.
- Second page: ( (2 -1) * 5) + 1 = 6, and so on.

Then it can be `currentPage  * itemsPerPage`. Eg if the current page is 1, then  1 * 5 = 5, if its the second page it will be: 2 * 5 = 10. Look below for an example:

```js
var pagination = {
 total: result.length,
 per_page: itemsPerPage,    
 current_page: currentPage, 
 last_page: Math.ceil(result.length / itemsPerPage),
 from: ((currentPage -1) * itemsPerPage) + 1,
 to: currentPage  * itemsPerPage
};
```

```html
Total = 15;
per_page = 5;
currentPage = 1;
last_page = truncate (15 / 5) = 3;
from: ((1-1) * 5) + 1 = 1 //first page
      ((2-1) * 5) + 1 = 6 //second page
to: 1 * 5 = 5 //first page
    2 * 5 = 10 // second page
From 1 to 5 // first page
From 6 to 10 // second page
From 11 to 15 // last page
```

Comment: This `to` is wrong, see it live on https://snack.expo.io/6kaxfQGzP , in this example I have 9 entries, the last page should have `to=8` because list length is `8`, and in the demo it is written `9` which is the last available row and not the last entry.

Comment: This calculate the right `to` using the offset :  `const offset = total % perPage; const to = (page + 1) * perPage - (page + 1 === numberOfPages && offset !== 0 ? perPage - offset : 0);`

Answer (score 5):

The answer above in the form of a function:

```
function pagination(length, currentPage, itemsPerPage) {
    return {
        total: length,
        per_page: itemsPerPage,
        current_page: currentPage,
        last_page: Math.ceil(length / itemsPerPage),
        from: ((currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage) + 1,
        to: currentPage * itemsPerPage
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this function, a guard could be added so that `to` doesn't print wrong result on the last page, e.g. `to: currentPage * itemsPerPage < length ? currentPage * itemsPerPage : length`

Answer (score 2):

last_page should use `Math.ceil()`, so that there is no floating point number. 0.4 will be 1 then, which is correct. 
from should be `itemsPerPage * (pageNumber - 1)` - this assumes that the value is 0-based and the pageNumber starts at 1. 
to should then be Math.min() of `itemsPerPage * pageNumber` and `total.length`, so that either the from-count plus itemsPerPage is used or, if this value is bigger than the total item count, the total item count is used.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that gets here in the future, the ticked answer has the "from" formula right. The "to" formula is inaccurate on occasions where the last page has fewer values than the "per_page" value. You can get the "to" value like this:

```
// Here we want to know the total number of pages possible, we are rounding up to the nearest integer because if the total number of items is
// not divisible by the numbers of items per page, then there has to be an extra page to list those last items

const numberOfPages = Math.ceil(total/per_page);

// here, we check if the number of pages is same value as our current page, this lets us know if we are on the last page or not
// if we are on the last page, we calculate the "to" value for that would be the "previous page" (this works even if we are on the very first page though)
// and we add the length of the current list to the value

const to = numberOfPages === current_page ? (per_page * (current_page - 1)) + {{length of the current list in this page}} : per_page * current_page;

// For anyone who does not understand tenary operators, the line const to =... is the same as writing

let to;
if ( numberOfPages === current_page){
  to = (per_page * (current_page - 1)) + {{length of the current list in this page}}
} else {
 to = per_page * current_page
}
```