# Based on a value show paginations in React

Tags: reactjs

So for example I have a variable as following `const articles = 115`, and from that value I want to calculate how many paginations by 10 will be. So I can iterate and show a div for each 10 articles.

For example:
`115 to be shown as 12 paginations to switch from, the last 5 is counted as one even if sot full 10.`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What you are asking about isn't clear. More people will be able to help you if you provide more in depth explanation and example of the code you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking from the calculation perspective you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39671363/5045126) another answer from another thread at Stack overflow

If you do want to use an already UI library that makes it for you, [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/) is an example of an MUI library